# iOS development: UITableView & segues

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, segue

I'm trying to implement a to-do-list app in swift 3, but the app has muliple info that will be entered by the user. First view (view 1) will have a tableView only, and when the + button is pressed, another view (view 2)  will be shown that has multiple textFields so that user can enter whatever info he/she wishes. After that, a row will be added to the tableView. 
When that row is pressed, a different view (view 3) will be shown that displays the info that was entered in view 2

In order to develop such app, is it like I'm gunna have one view that has the UITableView ( view 1 )? another one to let the user enter whatever info he/she wants ( view 2 )? and a third one to display all of the info entered in view 2?

Really sorry for the long question

Comment: master(vc1) - detail(vc3), pop over(vc2)

Comment: could you explain little bit more?

Comment: You could create a new project, choose Master-Detail Application, and see it.

Comment: Please explain more via your code here.

Answer (score 0):

VC1-->+ pressed --> push VC2 (textfield entry) -->Save --> pop to VC1

same way

VC1--> select row  -->push VC3 (details view) --> back(pop) to VC1